# React Hooks like ComponentDidMount, not using render counts

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is there a way to have a hook know when the react has totally finished rendering / mounted?

Not like..

```
const mountedRef = useRef(false);
useEffect(() => {
  if (mountedRef.current) {
    return 
  }
  // sync to database
}, [blogtitle])
```

This just keeps track of times render is called.

Is there way to use hooks to ACTUALLY be equivalent to componentDidMount?

Comment: The wording "actually equivalent to cDM" makes me want to ask the use case. Hooks have a different architecture, and the usage is different. Going for an "actual equivalente" is a bad architecture decision.  If you update your question to show your use case, I could perhaps point you to a better direction, hopefully that works for you

Comment: I'm initializing (dispatching an object from fetch to Redux). When users start to type, I auto-save the blog to the server. While the fetch is happening, blog#title is null. But when it comes back via fetch, it is dispatched to Redux. That change: Null to value received from fetch=>dispatch=>store causes React to render. I don't need to sync w DB again.. only when USER changes the title.

Comment: Are you talking about an infinite re-render loop problem, or are you worried about an extra 1 render that happens?

Answer (score 1):

Notice the removal of `blogtitle` below. This useEffect() is the equivalent of componentDidMount as it will only run on initial render.

```
const mountedRef = useRef(false);
useEffect(() => {
  if (mountedRef.current) {
    return 
  }
  // sync to database
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a function from useEffect. The returned function automatically called by React once the update finishes. You can check this post: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup